# CATransform3D with frames effect

Tags: ios, graphics, core-graphics, core-animation

I'm using this code to rotate sublayers around z-axis.

```
self.layer.sublayers[1].transform = CATransform3DMakeRotation((steps*22.5) / 180.0 * M_PI, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0);
self.layer.sublayers[2].transform = CATransform3DMakeRotation((eighter*45.0) / 180.0 * M_PI, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0);
self.layer.sublayers[3].transform = CATransform3DMakeRotation((quarter*90.0) / 180.0 * M_PI, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0);
self.layer.sublayers[4].transform = CATransform3DMakeRotation((half*180.0) / 180.0 * M_PI, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0);
```

But iOS make it very smooth with the "easy" effect. How can I change it to a blink effect? The sublayer must move to next position without visible trajectory,
hide on startPoint, and show on finalPoint.

Comment: what is "blink" effect and what is "easy" effect? i have no clue what you mean especially when you state "Sublayer must move to next position without visible trajectory. Hide on startPoint, show on finalPoin" do you mean the "Animation" effect that's applied for you?

Comment: Yes.
Can i make animation, without animation effect? (If you want) )))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if i'm understanding the question, you can disable animations by using a CATransaction block and disabling  actions like this.

```
[CATransaction begin];
[CATransaction setDisableActions:YES];
 //perform transforms here
[CATransaction commit];
```

Comment: @IvanTrubnikov great ... please accept the answer as correct. Thanks